# camel path syntax for select query and transferring the data into insert query for postgresql

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel, postgresql-9.4

I am using camel 2.15 and java 1.7 for my enterprise application. Our database is  postgresql 9.4.0.

I am trying to configure camel route for a scenario where my requirement is to read data from one postgresql schema with a select query and insert the same data into another postgresql schema.

I have used the below syntax for fetching the data from postgresql -

```
from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer()).threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances()).setBody(constant(serverData.getSql())).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId() + "?outputType=SelectList").
process(custom application logic)
```

With the above syntax, I can able to fetch the data and able to process into custom logic present in `process` method.

Note - In the above syntax, `serverData` class is used to get the postgresql connection details and sql details.

Now, my problem is - how do I define the camel route so that selected data can be directly inserted into another postgresql table by an insert query.

I have tried using below syntax without any success.

```
from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer()).threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances()).setBody(constant(serverData.getSql())).
setBody(constant("insert into new_raw_table (numbersubscribers,id) values(:?numbersubscribers,:?id)")).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId()).
process(custom application logic)
```

OR

```
from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer()).threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances()).setBody(constant(serverData.getSql())).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId() + "?consumer.onConsume=insert into new_raw_table(NumberSubscribers,ID) values(:#NumberSubscribers,:#ID)");
process(custom application logic)
```

Neither syntax can insert the selected data from one postgresql to another postgresql schema.

Comment: Are the two schemas in the same database (and server)? Then you can just use: `insert into schema2.table_name (col1) select col1 from schema1.table_name`

Comment: No, two schemas are in different database. And I need to have two action. First - to fetch the data from one database, Second - to insert the data into another database. These two action need to be in same camel route so that these action can be performed in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 query but only one jdbc endpoint. I think, you need to use another one jdbc endpoint with another datasource, because you have another database.

But this does not solve the problem of two queries in a single transaction. More information about transactional client can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html

UPDATED 2:

```
from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer())
  .threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances())
  .setBody(constant(serverData.getSql()))
  .to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId())
  //Think about query parameters, based on first query result
  //You need to define them, by default the result is returned in the OUT body 
  //ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> in the OUT body
   .to("log:before-split?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
   .split(body()) //because you received more then one record
   .to("log:after-split?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
   .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            //Record of first query after splitter in the Map
            Map<String, Object> record = exchange.getOut().getBody(Map.class);
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("numbersubscribers",  record.get("numbersubscribers"));
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("id",  record.get("id"));
        }
    })
   .to("log:before2query?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
   .setBody(constant("insert into new_raw_table (numbersubscribers,values(:?numbersubscribers,:?id)"))

  .to("jdbc:".....) //You have to refer here to another datasource, maybe like below
 //jdbc:embeddedDataSource?allowNamedParameters=true&outputType=SelectOne&useHeadersAsParameters=true&resetAutoCommit=false
  .process(custom application logic);
```

Comment: I have tried the option that you mentioned but I am getting issue in named parameter resolution. Though camel is getting the column name properly but it is unable to map it with the named parameters in the insert query. I am giving below the stack trace.  Cannot find key [numbersubscribers] in message body or headers to use when setting named parameter in query [insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)] on the exchange: Exchange[Message: insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)]

Comment: Exchange[
 Id                  ID-5CG4525D29-52989-1450858013400-0-2
 ExchangePattern     InOnly
 Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-5CG4525D29-52989-1450858013400-0-1, CamelJdbcColumnNames=[numbersubscribers, id], CamelJdbcRowCount=2, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0, firedTime=Wed Dec 23 13:36:55 IST 2015}
 BodyType            String
 Body                insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)

Comment: org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException: Cannot find key [numbersubscribers] in message body or headers to use when setting named parameter in query [insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)] on the exchange: Exchange[Message: insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)]
 at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.DefaultJdbcPrepareStatementStrategy$1.next(DefaultJdbcPrepareStatementStrategy.java:99)

Comment: Ok, you recived more then one record by query. I think you need to split result and manually set headers by query result in Processor, before you set new body (second query). I  updated my answer.

Comment: Ok. Now my camel route syntax is below -

Comment: `from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer()).threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances()).setBody(constant(serverData.getSql())).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId()).
split().body(List.class).`

Comment: `process(new Processor() {
 @Override
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
     //Record of first query after splitter in the Map
     Map<String, Object> record = exchange.getOut().getBody(Map.class);
     exchange.getIn().setHeader("numbersubscribers",  record.get("numbersubscribers"));
     exchange.getIn().setHeader("id",  record.get("id"));
 }
 }
).`

Comment: `setBody(constant("insert into new_raw_table_test (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)")).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId()+"?allowNamedParameters=true&outputType=SelectOne&useHeadersAsParameters=true&resetAutoCommit=false").
process(new SQLProcessor(serverData));`

Comment: And with this syntax, camel process got stuck after printing the below line -    15/12/23 19:17:44 INFO impl.DefaultCamelContext: Apache Camel 2.15.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.535 seconds. And there is no further response from camel process. I am thinking that somehow proper camel route not getting build with the above syntax and hence camel is failing to progress further.

Comment: Try to use logging before splitter `.to("log:before-split?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")` and inside processor or before processor. Route is working, but nothing pass through splitter, i think.

Comment: And try split result like here: `.split(body())`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alexey for your suggestion to add logging.

This is how it worked for me. Camel route syntax would be -

```
from("timer://foo?period="+serverData.getTimer()).threads(serverData.getNumberOfInstances()).setBody(constant(serverData.getSql())).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId()).
split(body()).process(new Processor() {
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
       Map<String, Object> record = exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class);
       exchange.getIn().setHeader("numbersubscribers",  record.get("numbersubscribers"));
       exchange.getIn().setHeader("id",  record.get("id"));
 }
}).
setBody(constant("insert into test_table (numbersubscribers, id) values(:?numbersubscribers, :?id)")).
to("jdbc:" + serverData.getUrl() + serverData.getUserId()+"?allowNamedParameters=true&outputType=SelectOne&useHeadersAsParameters=true&resetAutoCommit=false");}
```

In my scenario, select query data is present as "InOnly" exchange pattern, so when I was doing `exchange.getOut().getBody(Map.class)` to get the data it was throwing me **null pointer exception**. With the logging I found out the type of exchange pattern and corrected to `exchange.getIn().getBody(Map.class)` and that worked fine.

For future reference I am listing down the log stack trace.

```
  Exchange[
  , Id: ID-5CG4525D29-58712-1450892474425-0-2
  , ExchangePattern: InOnly
  , Properties: {CamelCreatedTimestamp=Wed Dec 23 23:11:16 IST 2015,        CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=threads1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=setBody1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=to1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=to2]], CamelTimerCounter=1, CamelTimerFiredTime=Wed Dec 23 23:11:16 IST 2015, CamelTimerName=foo, CamelTimerPeriod=15000, CamelToEndpoint=log://before-split?level=INFO&multiline=true&showAll=true}
  , Headers: {breadcrumbId=ID-5CG4525D29-58712-1450892474425-0-1, CamelJdbcColumnNames=[numbersubscribers, id], CamelJdbcRowCount=2, firedTime=Wed Dec 23 23:11:16 IST 2015}
  , BodyType: java.util.ArrayList
  , Body: [{numbersubscribers=11, id=22}, {numbersubscribers=55, id=66}]
```

This might help others facing similar issue(s). Thanks.